# It is possible to trade items in Pokemon ORAS without trading Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

My friend has Pokemon Omega Ruby and I have Pokemon Alpha Sapphire. He is selling his 3ds, and I'm trading his old Pokemon to my save.

But I cannot seem to pass items directly by trade, only attaching it to Pokemon, which is tedious. Is there an easier way to trade items in Pokemon ORAS?

Comment: Two answers, 55 minutes apart...5 reputation difference...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, none of the Pokemon games have any way of trading items other than attaching them to a Pokemon and trading it.

Comment: I was hoping that has another way, but this confirms my suspects that hasn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can trade back and forth the same Pokémon holding an item. This way, you won't loose Pokémon, but get the item(s). There is no way to trade items without Pokémon, as stated by the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a alternative to not do that. I did this to pass my friend's megaevolution stones, but it's a boring work, and takes a lot of time.

Comment: @RaduqSantos - Generally you don't need *every* item - trade over Mega Stones, Master Balls, hard to get Berries (only really need one each for growing) and Ability Capsules. The rest of the items can pretty much be found, bought or earned with relative ease. If you're trading over battle-ready Pokemon, they'll probably already have their needed item attached to it as well.

Comment: @Robotnik - I wanted to trade all the ultraballs, that costs a certain amount of game's money. All the megastone i already got.

Comment: Instead of trading all the ultra balls, just throw the amulet coin on your leading Pokemon and spam the Prize Money O-Power on the E4. That will build up your money pretty quickly and you can buy all the ultra balls again.

Comment: @RaduqSantos No problem! If I remember correctly, the money O-Power for lvl 1 is 1.5*, lvl 2 is 2* and lvl 3 is 3*. So if you beat someone with 5,000 prize, amulet coin would double it to 10,000. Lvl 3 OP would give you 15,000 = total should be 25,000 if I'm thinking the mechanics work this way. Either way, you can make money pretty quickly, I do it all the time in the games.

Comment: While you're at it, use the Bargain O-Power when purchasing. At level 3, it's a full 50% off the price of items

Comment: Money wasn't a problem at all indeed, in oras.